# ndk-build guess wrong about "template" of qualifier in C++. It's just variable name in C

Tags: android, android-ndk

I get error like this when I do ndk-build:

```
/Users/../handle.c:80: error: 'struct _AR2Tracking2DParamT' has no member named 'template'
/Users/../handle.c:100: error: 'struct _AR2Tracking2DParamT' has no member named 'template'
```

I didn't know about "template", so searched about it on google. Finally, I know it's the qualifier of C++.

But handle.c is a C file. Why does ndk-build incorrectly guess that its a C++ file?

Is there any way to specify it is a C file in Android.mk?

thanks.

---

2013/11/22 edit:

Sorry I put another error code. Relevant error code is the following:

-- template.h --

```
int            ar2FreeTemplate( AR2TemplateT  *template  );
```

-- ndk-build says --

```
/Users/.../template.h:63: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'template'
```

so ndk-build incorrectly guesses that template.h is C++ header file.

If it understands that it is a C header file, it should analyze `template` as a variable, not a keyword.

---

2013/11/25 edit:

here is template.h.
I replaced "template" to "temp". So i fixed this issue for the moment.

```
#ifndef AR2_TEMPLATE_H
#define AR2_TEMPLATE_H
#include <AR/ar.h>
#include <AR2/config.h>
#include <AR2/imageSet.h>
#include <AR2/featureSet.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

(An omission)

AR2TemplateT  *ar2GenTemplate ( int ts1, int ts2 );
int            ar2FreeTemplate( AR2TemplateT  *temp  );

int ar2SetTemplateSub ( ARParamLT *cparamLT, float  trans[3][4], AR2ImageSetT *imageSet,
                        AR2FeaturePointsT *featurePoints, int num,
                        AR2TemplateT *temp );

int ar2GetBestMatching ( ARUint8 *img, ARUint8 *mfImage, int xsize, int ysize, int pixFormat,
                         AR2TemplateT *mtemp, int rx, int ry,
                         int search[3][2], int *bx, int *by, float *val);
int ar2GetBestMatching2(void);

int ar2GetResolution( ARParamLT *cparamLT, float  trans[3][4], float  pos[2], float  dpi[2] );
int ar2GetResolution2( ARParam *cparam, float  trans[3][4], float  pos[2], float  dpi[2] );

int ar2SelectTemplate( AR2TemplateCandidateT *candidate, AR2TemplateCandidateT *prevFeature, int num,
                       float  pos[4][2], int xsize, int ysize );



#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `template` is a [reserved word](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) in C++. Therefore, you cannot use this as identifier in C++ context, even in an h file included from C++, even if you wrap it with `extren "C"`, as

```
extern "C" {
    #include "template.h"
}
```

The best solution would be to change the name of parameter in `template.h`. If the file is carved in stone, here is a workaround:

```
extern "C" {
    #define template notemplate
    #include "template.h"
    #undef template
}
```